# apache tiles creates multiple ids

Tags: java, spring, tiles

I am creating java web application using spring mvc and apache tiles. I have a problem with the HTML-element-ids of the elements in the page.
Because I am using tiles, I have a layout and two containers  - a places where I can put my content according the user request. This is my layout:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles" %>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <tiles:insertAttribute name="container1"/>
    <tiles:insertAttribute name="container2"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Assume I have a content.jsp page with input elements:

```
<input type="text" name="abc" id="abcInput" />
<input type="text" name="def" id="defInput" />
```

Now I want to use content.jsp both for container1 and container2. The problem is that that way I will get a page with duplicate Ids: abcInput and defInput will appear twice in the page. Is there a way to control on the ids?